# PM2 Common Settings For All Processes in JSON File

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, pm2

I am currently starting multiple Node.js processes using `pm2`. These processes are defined in a JSON file, which is used by running

```
pm2 start pm2.json
```

As you can see from the JSON file below, there is a lot of repetition. For example, making a change to the `error_file` location or setting the variable `time` to `true` involves a lot of repetition, which can be tedious with 10-20 such scripts defined in the JSON file.

Is it possible to simplfy the JSON file by setting `time` variable only once in the file and have it apply to all processes?

Also, is it possible to use a template to define `error_file` and `out_file`, such as `"../logs/${name}-error.log"`?

**Example pm2.json**

```
{
    "apps": [
      {
        "name": "foo-a",
        "script": "./foo/a.js",
        "args": "-e apple",
        "error_file": "../logs/foo-a-error.log",
        "out_file": "../logs/foo-a-out.log",
        "time": true
      },
      {
        "name": "foo-b",
        "script": "./foo/b.js",
        "args": "-e banana",
        "error_file": "../logs/foo-b-error.log",
        "out_file": "../logs/foo-b-out.log",
        "time": true
      },      {
        "name": "bar-c",
        "script": "./bar/c.js",
        "args": "-e cranberry",
        "error_file": "../logs/bar-c-error.log",
        "out_file": "../logs/bar-c-out.log",
        "time": true
      },

      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `js` file instead `json` file, it will allow you to create and use common variable/function for `repetition part`.

```
const time = true

module.exports = {
    "apps": [
      {
        "name": "foo-a",
        "script": "./foo/a.js",
        "args": "-e apple",
        "error_file": "../logs/foo-a-error.log",
        "out_file": "../logs/foo-a-out.log",
        "time": time
      },
      {
        "name": "foo-b",
        "script": "./foo/b.js",
        "args": "-e banana",
        "error_file": "../logs/foo-a-error.log",
        "out_file": "../logs/foo-a-out.log",
        "time": time
      },      {
        "name": "bar-c",
        "script": "./bar/c.js",
        "args": "-e cranberry",
        "error_file": "../logs/bar-c-error.log",
        "out_file": "../logs/bar-c-out.log",
        "time": time
      },

      ...
```

Comment: Awesome! Looks like we can also dynamically generate the objects in the `apps` array for values like `error_file` and `out_file`, which are `\`${log_path}/${name}-error.log\``